# What's a reasonable delay before getting feedback from a reopen edit?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

### Context

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/438614/how-to-implement-automatic-semver-from-code-changes) was closed because it was not focused enough.

I've edited it within a day or two.

As of writing this, **11 days** have passed since my edit and I did not get any feedback.

- The question was not reopen.
- No comments were added.

Perhaps the question is still not good enough. However if that's the case, I would assume that I should get some sort of feedback from the edit... eventually?

### Interrogations

1. When an edit is submitted in order to reopen a question, after how much time should feedback be expected?

   > You should get feedback within [**N±M**] days after your edit.
2. What can the question authors do after that time?

   > If you don't get any feedback within [N±M] days after submitting your edit, please [**do something**].

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site is not a high frequency site like Stackoverflow - sometimes things take time, and - believe it or not - sometimes even very active community members are bound to other things in life for days, weeks or months.

However, after 11 days, I don't think much will happen to the specific question in stake any more. The question expresses an expectation for a tool which can only be partially fulfilled, this hasn't changed by the edit, and it was already mentioned in the comments. And it asks directly if a tool exists which might do what you envisioned - but tool recommendation questions are off-topic for this site, which makes me (and probably others, too), quite reluctant to cast a reopen vote. Note also the question already got an upvoted answer - so I (and maybe others) don't see any need to take any further action on this.

IMHO there is no *general rule* when feedback might be expected. This depends too much on the question and the specific circumstances. But when all you want to know is how much time you should wait until you ask here on meta for feedback, my personal limit would be around 3 days at least, maybe a week.